# Read data file to array , Pass to member function - lost

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am a newbie to C++  .  i am trying to , i think, answer this question  and i am lost many hours wasted.  I think I've broken the problem down correctly.

Issues: I can read data from the file ( it has to columns) but i cant read it into an object from a file with two columns.

so the object functions can store it to calculate the gross

// here is  what I have... can anyone help me ...i know this is probably simple but I'm complete confused and i have to understand arrays and classes before I move on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

Class  Payroll

{
private:
int hours;
double rate, gross;

public:
Payroll()     // default constructor
{
    hours = rate = 0;
}

// Set

     void setHours(int h)
{   hours = h;  }

void setRate(double r)

{   rate = r;   }

//  Get 
double getGross (int hours, double rate r])

{
    gross =  hours * rate;
    return gross;
}

};
// trying write a function that take array display results
void showfunction(int array[],int); // lost here too!

int main ()
{

Payroll sevenObjects[7];

const int EMP_RATE = 7 ;// sets number of Employees
const int EMP_HOURS = 7; 
int hours [EMP_HOURS];
double rate [EMP_RATE];
int count ;
ifstream datafile;  //  used to read  data

datafile.open ("payroll.dat");     // Open file
    if( !datafile)
        cout << "error opening data file \n";
    else
    {                                

  /*  i tried  nested and getline, probably wrong. i tried  2D  Array[][] but didnt      know how to pass to member function */          

        for (count = 0 ; count < lines; count++)
           {
            >> hours[count]>>rate[count];      
          cout << hours[count]<<"  " <<rate[count]<< endl;

            }
       }
         datafile.close();
  return 0;
  }
```

payroll

```
40.0          10.00
38.5          9.50
16.0      7.50
22.5      9.50
40.0      8.00
38.0      8.00
40.0      9.00
```

Comment: I'd start by fixing your compilation errors.

Comment: Please don't paste *entire* assignment descriptions unless *necessary*, which is rarely the case.

Comment: ok thank you , I see I was limiting my self,  i didn't think that I could get data from a file the fashion that you did.   datafile >> hours >> rate; . thank you I won't post the whole thing next time

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change your `getGross` method:

```
double getGross()
{
     gross =  hours * rate;
     return gross;
}
```

Actually, it would be better to have `CalculateGross` and `getGross` methods, but it's up to you.

Probably easiest to understand way to read your data:

```
for (count = 0 ; count < lines; count++)
{
    int hours;
    double rate;

    // read everything in temporary variables;
    datafile >> hours >> rate;      
    sevenObjects[count].setHours(hours);
    sevenObjects[count].setRate(rate);

}
```

As for printing functions, you can design something like this:

```
void showfunction(Payroll *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Gross: " << array[i].getGross() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  MiXaeL I think I get it .  *array is an array pointer?  but I have 2 values that I am passing back to the member function in one array?

Comment: `*array` is essentially the same thing as `array[]`, since `array` is a pointer to its beginning. And in that case it's array of Payrolls, so each member has all the values and methods of Payroll class.